# What does it mean by Heartbeat in terms of micro-services?

Tags: microservices, netflix-eureka

I was reading an article about eureka and it said :

> if there are two clients registered to a Eureka instance, each one sending a heartbeat every 30s

What is a heartbeat? what information is sent in a heartbeat?

Answer (score 4):

Heartbeats are simple requests to microservice's API. Usually, for REST APIs you send `GET /healthcheck`, that should respond with HTTP status 200. If the request fails or takes awfully long, it means that microservice is dead or hanged, and load balancer should not direct any requests to it.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Is there any documentation where I can find this in detail ?

Comment: I did not describe any specific implementation, just wrote up how generally it would be done.

Comment: Ok I meant how do you this is how it is been done. Have you read it somewhere or looked into the code of some implementation or its an educated guess or some expert told you?

Comment: this is not an heartbeat, this is an "Healthcheck"

Comment: this answer is right. take a look at this document https://martinfowler.com/articles/patterns-of-distributed-systems/heartbeat.html

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi__service_discovery_eureka_clients.html#_registering_with_eureka):

> When a client registers with Eureka, it provides meta-data about
>   itself — such as host, port, health indicator URL, home page, and
>   other details. Eureka receives heartbeat messages from each instance
>   belonging to a service. If the heartbeat fails over a configurable
>   timetable, the instance is normally removed from the registry.

[Eureka](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi__service_discovery_eureka_clients.html#_eureka_s_health_checks) uses the client heartbeat to determine if a client is up.

There are multiple health indicators such as:

- DiskSpaceHealthIndicator
- RefreshScopeHealthIndicator
- HystrixHealthIndicator

HealthCheckHandler maps that status into one of the Eureka-supported statuses. This status will then be propagated to the Eureka server through heartbeats.